# Reflection Linq-Entity "IN()" function for "contains" searching group of integers

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, reflection

I'm building my own reflection functions for certain types of searches.

The problem is that I want to search a group of IDs within a list of IDs and filter my search/select query to have only these specific objects.

**This is the same as using "IN()" in Linq-Entity framework. But I can't use a.objid.**

```
return query.Where(a => ObjectsToFind.Contains(a.objid));
```

However, "a.objid" is causing errors because I use T Template.

So a is "T a" instead of "MyTable a" so that I can call it's "objid" property.

I know there is a way to do this with parameter expressions. However, I can't figure it out.

Here's what I tried to replace that above line with:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereFunctionContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string contains)
{    
    var ObjectsToFind = new List<int>(); // I want to search IN() this function that gets filled in here.
    ObjectsToFind = FillObjectsToFind(); // just the object id integers I want to filter
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, "objid"); // I look for this
    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(int) }); // int type
    var vars = Expression.Variable(List<int>,); // I can't use "constant", but what do I use here?
    var containsExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, method, vars);
    return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsExpression, parameter));
}
```

Replacing "T" with the actual table entity, causes a lot of problems, so I decided to keep the T.

---

```
else if (s.ST == "function")
{ // search func
    myTable a;
    DC2 = MyUtility.WhereFunctionContains(DC2, a => a.objid, s.S);
    // s.S is my search query string.
    // s.ST means I'm searching for functions (from another associated table)
    // I don't understand how a.objid gets called, I wanted to use Template/Reflections.
}
```

Here's how I call Zev's function.

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereFunctionContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, int>> converter, string contains)
{
    FunctionsClass fc = new FunctionsClass();
    var ObjectsToFind = new List<int>();
    ObjectsToFind = fc.SearchContainFunction(contains); // I grabbed my list of IDs to search
    return query.Where(t => ObjectsToFind.Contains(converter(t)));
}
```

Comment: Can you include in your question what is the type of `ObjectsToFind` ?

Comment: `causing errors because I use T Template` this is because your `template` misses some restriction info such as by using `where T : ...`

Comment: ObjectsToFind ===> List<int>()

Comment: @KingKing I'm using a function like this: public static IQueryable<T> WhereFunctionContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string contains)

Comment: Essentially I need a reflective, Template method of filtering an IQueryable with a LIST of INTs according to "objid" parameter/field in the IQueryable table.

Comment: @KingKing , you nailed it. I didn't realize that I could do "where T: MyEntityFrameworkClass"  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a number of queries on different types:

```
IQueryable<Person> personsQry = ...
IQueryable<Sale>   salesQry   = ...
IQueryable<Order>  ordersQry  = ...
```

and you have a method that generates a `List<int>`, called `FillObjectsToFind`:

```
public List<int> FillObjectsToFind()
{
    //code here
}
```

You want to be able to limit each of the above queries to only have the id in the returned list. As an added bonus, this should be an extension method, so you can call it like this:

```
var personsFiltered = personsQry.WhereFunctionContains(...);
var salesFiltered   = salesQry.WhereFunctionContains(...);
var ordersFiltered  = ordersQry.WhereFunctionContains(...);
```

The problem is each query is of a separate type, and you would prefer to write one method that covers all of them.

---

The first part of the solution is to define a generic method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereFunctionContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    //code here
}
```

but there is still a problem: the only type we know of is type `T` which is not a real type, but a placeholder for actual types. Since these types could be anything -- `string`, `System.Random`, `SqlConnection`, an ASP.NET `Label`, a WPF `TextBlock` -- there is no way of knowing how to compare each object to a `List` of `ints`.

---

The most straightforward solution is to define an **interface**:

```
interface IHasObjID
{
    int ObjID {get;set;}
}
```

Then each type should implement this interface:

```
class Person : IHasObjID
{
    int objID;
    int ObjID
    {
        get {return objID;}
        set {objID = value;}
    }
}

//implement sales and orders similarly
```

Once that is done, you can define a **constraint** on the types allowed by the method. Now that the type definitely has an `ObjID` property, we can query on that:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereFunctionContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : IHasObjID
{
    var intsToFind = FillObjectsToFind();
    return query.Where(t => intsToFind.Contains(t.ObjID));
}
```

This is what **King King** was telling you in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834933/reflection-linq-entity-in-function-for-contains-searching-group-of-integer/18835713?noredirect=1#comment27786419_18834933) comment.

---

<del>I propose that when calling this function, you also pass in how to get at the integer from the type:</del>

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereFunctionContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T,int>> converter)
{    
    var intsToFind = FillObjectsToFind();
    return query.Where(t => intsToFind.Contains(converter(t)));
}
```

<del>However, I haven't tested this code, and since we are working with Entity Framework and expressions I suspect there is still an issue: An expression cannot be "called" within an expression.</del> 
I wanted to suggest the above, but it doesn't compile with the following error -- **'converter' is a 'variable' but used like a 'method'**.

After all that, the solution is straightforward, using `Join`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereFunctionContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T,int>> converter) 
{
    var ints = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return query.Join(ints,converter,i=>i,(t,i) => t);
}
```

to be called like this:

```
var filteredPersons = query.WhereFunctionContains(p => p.PersonID);
```

---

If this is only used with a single type `MyTable`:

```
public static IQueryable<MyTable> WhereFunctionContains(this IQueryable<MyTable> query)
{
    var ints = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return query.Join(ints, mt=>mt.objid, i=>i, (t,i) => t);
}
```

---

Some links from the [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/67ef8sbd.aspx) (in order of the answer):

- [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)
- [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/512aeb7t.aspx)

  - [Generic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/twcad0zb.aspx)
  - [Generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5x73970.aspx)
- [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx)
- [LINQ inner joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397941.aspx)

Also, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx) for a nice overview of LINQ operators, such as `Select`, `Where`, `Count` and `ToList`.

Comment: won't work for entity framework as this would execute in memory (due to `Func` rather than `Expression<Func>`

Comment: Also how would I call this function anyway? Please provide an example along with the function. (I don't know what converter looks like).

Comment: @DarrenKopp edited. With `Expression<Func>` does it work? Because the `List<int>` exists locally, and not on the database. Also, invoking `converter` may not be allowed. If that is the case, I would suggest using [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), iterating over the list and adding an `Or` clause to the predicate for each item in the list.

Comment: This code makes no sense to me. See my update above. How are you calling mt => mt.objid ??? We only have template T how can you call objid without using Reflection??

Comment: @Dexter Although `WhereFunctionContains` only defines `T`, in the call to `WhereFunctionContains` we are defining `query` as being `IQueryable<MyTable>`. The compiler then translates the `T` in this case to being `MyTable`, which means that `converter` in this case is an `Expression<Func<MyTable,int>>` and the lambda expression can use members of `MyTable`. (From your usage of the term **template** I assume you have a background in C++. C++ templates are not quite the same as .NET generics -- see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx).)

Comment: Yeah but I can't use my code like this: IQueryable<MyTable> query = query.WhereFunctionContains    Then there are conversion issues, because all my other cases return a IQueryable<T>.  Yes I do work with C++ more often in the past, there seems to be a lot of magic in C#.

Comment: How do I make my function so that WhereFunctionContains("objid", containsearchstring) returns an "IQueryable<T>"??? Maybe even add the List<int> here WhereFunctionContains("objid", ObjectsToSearchInThisQuery, containsearchstring);---I do not believe I can just use m => m.objid in this way.

Comment: Wow thanks for the amazing comment. My only problem now is that I can't implement the interface because my Table is an "Entity Framework class", and I don't know if I should mess with it by modifying it without knowing how Entity framework handles its classes. I have a generalized "Utility" class that takes in a IQueryable based on reflection of a certain Entity Framework class. I don't actually do MyTable.WhereFunctionContains(), I do Utility.WhereFunctionContains(MyIQueryableObject), and then I continue to modify, sort, limit etc. That Queryable is the correct type based on reflection.

Comment: Ok ok, what I did was use the "where T : MyTable" Then just started using the properties in my EntityFramework object. So I didn't need the interface, though I am curious to learn more about the tricks you were doing. I was able to call it like this: MyQuery = (IQueryable<T>)MyUtility.WhereFunctionContains((IQueryable<MyModel.MyTable>)MyQuery, searchContains); -- AND IT WORKS! Thanks!

Comment: @Dexter Re implementing interfaces on EF classes -- it is bit of a headache. You have to go and edit the T4 templates (files with a `.tt` extension) that VS uses to generate the EF classes, saying that each class should implement the interface, and specifying the members.

Comment: @Dexter Is all this just for a single type `MyTable`? If that is the case, are you sure you need a generic method?

Comment: @Dexter Updated my answer for if you are using a single type, as well as some links.

Comment: Yes but the problem is there is a lot of generic functions with generic type. So this function has to also return a T type otherwise, it won't work right (with sorting that comes later). So I used Where T, instead of the specific parameter type.